# VirtualBox: Opening appliance with 7zip

Tags: php

We have a PHP application that is inside a virtual machine (turnkey VirtualBox). We developed an installer that downloads virtualbox and imports the appliance. The user executed this installer to get the app.

But, we discovered that if the user has the 7zip and opens the appliance (.ova) he can navigate by the folders and get the PHP Code.

What can we do to block this "navigation with 7zip"? Like an appliance "encryption" or something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure your approach is feasible.

Comment: Without physical security, you can't really protect the source.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about infosec. It's about protecting your company's proprietary data.

Answer (score 3):

> But, we discovered that if the user has the 7zip and opens the appliance (.ova) he can navigate by the folders and get the PHP Code.

An .ova file is [simply a tar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) containing configurations and disk images for the appliance. 7zip allows the user to open the tar file and since 7zip supports various disk image formats the user can also look whats on the disk, i.e. your PHP files.
There are other ways to do this without using 7zip so it would not make any sense to develop any 7zip specific solution.

The cause of the problem is that you distribute the source code of your application to the user, even it is packed inside multiple containers (disk image, tar). You do this because your web application in the appliance needs to have access to these files. Encryption of the .ova or disk image inside will not help because in order to run the application these data need to be decrypted and once this is done the user can again access the data.

It is also not possible to encrypt the PHP code itself because the PHP interpreter needs the decrypted code. The best possibility to hide the code from the user is probably to [obfuscate](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+obfuscator) it so that it is still usable source code but unreadable enough for simple reverse engineering.

At the end you face the question tools like DVD players and other DRM solutions faced before: once you have shipped the application to the use you loose the control over it. As long as you have no control over the system of the user you can not limit the activities of the user. This means you can make the reverse engineering only harder but not impossible.

Answer (score -1):

You could create an encrypted LUKS partition that will be mounted on boot. Put all your data on that partition, and it will not be available unless the client boots Linux first.

Instructions from [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile):

1 - Create a random key file and make it readable only by root:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/keyfile bs=1024 count=4 

sudo chmod 0400 /root/keyfile
```

2 - Create a encrypted partition:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdX /root/keyfile
```

3 - Add the keyfile to crypttab:

```
sudo nano /etc/crypttab
```

4 - Add the following line to `crypttab`

```
sdX_crypt      /dev/sdX  /root/keyfile  luks
```

5 - Put it on `fstab` to mount on boot:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab 

/dev/mapper/sdX_crypt  /var/www     ext3    defaults        0       2
```

After you reboot, the `/var/www` directory will be mounted.

Comment: “it will not be available unless the client boots Linux first” That's such a small hurdle that it isn't worth bothering with this. You're adding complexity for zero security benefit.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what this will achieve. All the PHP files will be stored inside the Linux image, encrypted. It will be impossible to just fire up 7zip and extract the PHP files. Depending on the image configuration (no root access, no shell access), the client will not be able to do the same even after booting.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how little this achieves. It is impossible to just fire up 7zip and extract the PHP files. It is however possible to fire up 7zip and extract both the encrypted files and the key. Or to boot the machine with a rescue OS, edit `/etc/passwd` to open up the root account, and reboot under the normal OS. Sure, there are people who might not figure it out, but if you want to do it and don't understand how, it's one Stack Exchange question away.